# PRE tag removes leading whitespace

Tags: html

```
 #
#
```

becomes

```
#
#
```

Is there anyway to preserve that leading space right after the pre tag?

Comment: Are you sure it does get removed? http://jsbin.com/OWIpuHe/1/edit

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with how SyntaxHighlighter is handling the pre tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a SyntaxHighlighter issue. I've opened a but on GitHub. https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/issues/269

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the space in front of the item that you want the space to be there i.e.

`<pre> ####</pre>`

The `<pre>` tag takes the formatting exactly as you input it.